# G-WAN 4.1.17 can find its /csp scripts but not my old /csp scripts

Tags: acl, file-permissions, g-wan, selinux

After extracting the gwan (4.1.17) in a folders, I execute gwan in this folder. It works normally.
When I replace all the old gwan files and folders in my project folder from this extracted folder, gwan cannot find the c servlets, but still can find the files in www folder.

Who can explain this?

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to check for permissions issues is to start gwan as root, if not already doing so. If it works as root, but not otherwise, it's likely a permissions issue.

Comment: I ran g-wan(4.1.17) in my project folder as root (not in the extracted folder), it still couldn't find the c servlets.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue only in one of my virtual hosts, while all the rest work fine. I have contacted Pierre about this and he should be able to get this fixed very soon, but as of right now it's only been a day so he would have to provide a more detailed answer.

This didn't happen when I used the vanilla g-wan 4.1.17 install, all of those scripts worked fine. I would be interested to hear if you had been using a default listener/IP host configuration or virtual hosts in use.

Comment: I use ubuntu 12.10 and always keep updated. No virtual machine installed. G-wan listens to 0.0.0.0:8881. I changed to :8080, but the problem was still there. The error logs have no strange record, only said 404 file not found.

Answer (score 0):

> After extracting the gwan (4.1.17) in a folders, I execute gwan in this folder. It works normally.

Proof that this is not a G-WAN bug: all works fine when you *"execute gwan in its folder"*.

> When I replace all the old gwan files and folders in my project folder from this extracted folder, gwan cannot find the `c servlets`, but still can find the files in `www` folder.

This issue is most likely related to access rights: either the `C servlets` can't be read (by the account used to run gwan) or the compiled objects can't be used from your `/tmp` or `$TMPDIR` directory, see http://gwan.ch/faq#error8246.

File permissions are [notoriously tricky subject](http://old.nabble.com/Friendlier-EPERM---Request-for-input-td34878750.html):

*"Getting an EPERM/EACCES in userspace really kinda blows. As a user you don't have any idea why you got it. It could be SELinux, it could be rwx bits on the file, it could be a missing capability, it could be an ACL, it could be who knows what. 
[...]
Adding SELinux, ACL, and capabilities to systems made them so much easier to comprehend, didn't it? (My definition of "secure" includes understanding what the system is doing. Crazy, I know.) 
[...]
-EPERM was about file permissions. For SELinux and disability bits and whatever they're calling OS/2 extended attributes this week you need -EBUREAUCRACY."*